# How do I avoid a segmentation fault when calling a method on a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, shared-ptr

Sample program:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class D;

class C {
public:
  C();
  void callD();
  void replaceD(D* d);
private:
  std::shared_ptr<D> d;
};

class D {
public:
  D(C* c);
  void call();
private:
  virtual void print();
  C* c;
};

C::C() : d(new D(this)) {}

void C::callD() {
  d->call();
}

void C::replaceD(D* d) {
  this->d = std::shared_ptr<D>(d);
}

D::D(C* c) : c(c) {}

void D::call() {
  c->replaceD(new D(c));
  print();
}

void D::print() {
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}

int main(void) {
  auto c = new C();
  c->callD();
  return 0;
}
```

(With gcc: `g++ -std=c++11 tmp.cpp -o tmp && ./tmp`)

What happens:

- `C::callD()` calls `d->call()`
- `D::call()` calls `c->replaceD()`
- `C::replaceD()` reassigns the `C`’s `d` pointer, causing the old `d` to be deleted
- `D::call()` attempts to call the virtual method `print()` – but the current `d` instance was deleted by `C::replaceD()`!
- **Segmentation fault**

Workaround: Insert `auto d_ = d;` in `C::callD()` so that the `shared_ptr` isn’t deleted until `C::callD()` finishes. But that looks suspiciously like an optimizeable unused variable (though g++ doesn’t seem to remove it even on `-O3`).

Shouldn’t the refcount be increased on any `ptr->method()` call until `method()` returns, to avoid this problem where `method`’s `this` is prematurely deleted?

Comment: Please include a [MCV example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question, it's easier for everyone.

Comment: Is the gist not MCV?

Comment: It is better for it to be included in the question - that way if someone needs to refer to this question in the future they can be guaranteed to find the example code. If it is left as a gist the code could be deleted at which point the question becomes useless for anyone else.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I thought it might be a bit too long, but with the scrollbar it looks okay.

Comment: Can I ask what on earth you are trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: Do not use `new`. Use `make_shared` instead

Comment: Daniel: Well, the real example is a form of state machine, where `Thing` has a `ThingState`, and `ThingState.someMethod()` may (indirectly) call `Thing->setState(new OtherThingState())`, but will then still try to call some other method upon itself – segfault, since `Thing->setState` deleted the original `ThingState`.

Comment: Ed: Thanks, I’ll keep that in mind… but that’s not the cause of the problem here, right?

Comment: Use flywheel pattern? Can you make states into stateless singletons?

Comment: And do not use raw pointers

Comment: Arkadiy: No, sorry.

My solution, for now: take all `setState(…)` calls that don’t occur within a `checkForStateTransition()` method and rewrite them into `next_state = …`, then check the new field `next_state` in `checkForStateTransition()`.

Arguably, this is the way it should be done anyways – state transitions only occurring in a few well-defined places (here, `start()` and `checkForStateTransition()`). (For the record, this code wasn’t originally written by me.)

However, I’m still curious why `ptr->method()` doesn’t temporarily increase the use count. Is it unsound? Performance concerns?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `std::shared_ptr` reference into `C::replaceD` that can be given ownership of `C`s current `D` before it is deleted.

```
void C::replaceD(D* d, std::shared_ptr<D>& tmp)
{
    tmp.swap(this->d);
    this->d = std::shared_ptr<D>(d);
}
```

and then `D` can keep itself alive until the end of the `D::call`

```
void D::call()
{
    std::shared_ptr<D> tmp {};
    c->replaceD(new D(c), tmp);
    print();
}
```

I have to say though that your code seems poorly designed to me, and I would first consider if there's not a better design that would avoid this issue entirely.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn’t the refcount be increased on any ptr->method() call until method() returns, to avoid this problem where method’s this is prematurely deleted?

No.  The semantics of `std::shared_ptr` are strictly pointer references, not function calls.  The object needs to be referenced in another object or on the stack.  You're deleting the reference.

```
void C::replaceD(D* d) {
  this->d = std::shared_ptr<D>(d);
}
```

This code might as well be `delete this` instead of `c->replaceD(new D(c))`.

```
void D::call() {
  c->replaceD(new D(c));
  print();
}
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you need to keep the reference to `D` alive, you can rewrite `C::replaceD`.

```
std::shared_ptr<D> C::replaceD(D* d) {

  std::shared_ptr<D> old = this->d;

  this->d = std::shared_ptr<D>(d);

  return old;
}
```

Then rewrite `D::call`.

```
void D::call() {
  std::shared_ptr<D> prev = c->replaceD(new D(c));
  prev->print();
}
```